# Expand JSONB into columns with first row as template

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, dynamic-sql, jsonb

Let's say you have a Postgres table of the form:

```
 f1  | f2    |   metadata   
-----+-------+-----------------------
 a   | 33    | {"f3": "d", "f4": "e"}
 b   | 20    | {"f3": "d", "f4": "g"}
```

With the `metadata` column being an unstructured JSON field. How can I query this table such that the result records contain fields `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4`, with the JSON expanded to fill these fields?

I know `json_populate_record()` can do this if you know `f3` and `f4` are the field names beforehand. But I don't. I want to use the key names in `metadata` of the first row as template for all other rows.

In other words: I want the query's result columns to be `f1`, `f2` + *all the keys of the 1st row's JSON data*. Any other keys that do not conform to the ones in the first row shall be dropped.

Comment: What *do* you know about contained keys. Every bit is important. And I am not sure I understand your question: `What if I want the expanded columns to be the keys in the JSON of the first row of the table?`

Comment: Even though in the table above, both JSON data have the same keys (f3 and f4) it is possible the second one has differing keys from the first. I want the query result's columns to be `f1`, `f2` + the keys of the 1st row's JSON data. Any keys in other JSON data that do not conform to the first's will be dropped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no natural "first" row. You need to define "first".
Assuming the first row for `ORDER BY f1, f2`.

If you don't know the number and data types of columns to be expected this ***cannot* be done in a single SQL statement**. SQL demands to know the return type, at least at call time. But there are various ways to do it with two statements.

#### Step 0

Here is a proper test setup to work with:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (f1 text, f2 int, metadata jsonb);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('a', 33, '{"f3": "d", "f4": "e"}')  -- "first" row
, ('b', 20, '{"f3": "d", "f4": "g"}')  -- same keys
, ('c', 40, '{"f7": "x", "f4": "o"}')  -- one matching key
, ('d', 50, '{"f3": "o", "f9": "x", "f123": "z"}')  -- one match, two miss
, ('e', 60, '{"x": "d", "y": "g"}')    -- no match
, ('f', 33, '{"f3": 1, "f4": false}'); -- numeric and boolean
```

#### Step 1

Once you *know* ***number***, ***names*** and ***types*** of the result columns, it gets simple, like you mentioned in the question. I suggest you create a temporary table to provide the row type for [`jsonb_populate_record()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp(f3 text, f4 text) ON COMMIT DROP;

SELECT f1, f2, meta.*
FROM   tbl, jsonb_populate_record(NULL::tmp, metadata) meta;
ROLLBACK;  -- or: COMMIT;
```

[`ON COMMIT DROP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) drops the table at the end of the transaction automatically. You may or may not want that. If you do, use a single transaction for both commands.

Temporary tables are only visible in the same session, so there is no naming conflict with multiple transactions doing the same.

If you don't have this information, it get's more sophisticated.

#### Step 2

You can do the same with a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) command and dynamic SQL:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp(f3 text, f4 text) ON COMMIT DROP';
END
$do$;
```

#### Step 3

Since we do not actually know number and names of output columns we extract that information from the first row. Assumptions:

- Data type is `text` for all columns.
- The "first" row has at least one key in the `jsonb` column.
- Existing column names "f1" and "f2" are not repeated as keys in the JSON column. (Postgres allows duplicate names among output columns, but some clients have problems with that - and it's rather confusing.)

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
   SELECT (SELECT 'CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp('
                || string_agg(quote_ident(k), ' text, ')  -- f3 text, f4 
                || ' text) ON COMMIT DROP'
           FROM   jsonb_object_keys(metadata) k)
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY f1, f2
   LIMIT  1
   );

END
$do$;

SELECT f1, f2, meta.*
FROM   tbl, jsonb_populate_record(NULL::tmp, metadata) meta;
```

Voilá.

Be sure to properly escape key names with [`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) or similar.

**If column names were known in advance ...**
([addressing your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896111/expand-jsonb-into-columns-with-first-row-as-template/32899246?noredirect=1#comment53629085_32899246)), you could simply:

```
SELECT f1, f2, metadata->>'f3', metadata->>'f4'
FROM   tbl;
```

For wide rows, `jsonb_populate_record()` is much more convenient, though. You can still use the dynamic solution, or you persist a table or a type and use that.

#### Alternative

If your second command can ***depend*** on your first, you could also just build the simple statement dynamically and execute that in another call:

```
SELECT (SELECT 'SELECT f1, f2, metadata->>'
             || string_agg(format('%1$L AS %1$I', k), ', metadata->>')
             || ' FROM tbl'
        FROM   jsonb_object_keys(metadata) k)
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY f1, f2
LIMIT  1;
```

Returns above simple query as text. Execute that as second command ... Execution may be a bit faster, but it requires *two* round-trips to the server while the first solution can make do with just one ... You decide.

Using [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) here to simplify the safe query string concatenation.

Comment: I assume because were using 2 statements this is rather inefficient, right?

Comment: @sddhhanover: Actually, no. It has some non-trivial, constant overhead for the table creation, which can amount to something if you execute it often. But it's relatively cheap. An index to support your `ORDER BY` clause would be instrumental.

Comment: If the column names were known in advance, would creating a temporary table still be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @sddhhanover: Then it would be trivial, see addendum.

Comment: Also, I'm just trying to understand this - where does the `k` variable come from? I know it stores the result of jsonb_object_keys(metadata) but I don't see where it is assigned that value.

Comment: @sddhhanover: It's table and column alias for the set-returning function here: `jsonb_object_keys(metadata) k` (short for: `jsonb_object_keys(metadata) AS k(k)`. I also added another alternative solution.

Comment: If the JSON keys are recorded as type TEXT in another table which can be JOINed to this one, can all this be done in one query? For instance, if the table `keys` was a 1-column table, where each row was a JSON key to be extracted.

Comment: @sddhhanover: This question is overloaded a bit already. I suggest you present your new idea in a new question. You can always link to this one for context.